# When I try to compile with g++ it is not parsing the flags I pass

Tags: makefile, compilation, g++

In my makefile I wrote:

```
all:
        g++ -g -Wall main.cpp -o a.out
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
make: g++ -g -Wall: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is that you're not using a simple text editor to create your makefile, and instead of standard ASCII spaces between the words in `g++ -g -Wall` you've used some kind of alternative Unicode whitespace character which appears as a space to you, but which is not recognized as a space to GNU make.

All makefiles should be encoded using UTF-8, and they should all use traditional ASCII characters (e.g., a space character is ASCII code 32).

Comment: Thank you, that was it ! ! !